# Boostrap 4 my-auto no funciona

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Estoy tratando de centrar un *card-body* y estoy aplicando el centrado tanto vertical como horizontal, aquí el código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>
            Test 
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row my-auto mx-auto">
            <div class="card card-body my-auto mx-auto">
                I am Groot.
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </div>
     
</html>
```

Y como resultado estoy obteniendo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo por que sucede, ¿Acaso faltara algún enlace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En bootstrap 4 tienes la opción de flexbox, puedes ver más aquí https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row text-center h-100">
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center my-auto">
    <div class="card card-block d-flex" style="height: 80px">
      <div class="card-body align-items-center d-flex justify-content-center">
        I am Groot.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: (y) mil gracias!

Comment: A ti. Bienvenido.